# Elmasri Employee Database - Determining those working at different locations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on the Elmasri Employee DB. Please refer to this document [document](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwjS8OnAjvHXAhXEQBoKHeX4BLQQFghPMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.psau.edu.sa%2Ffiledownload%2Fdoc-8-pptx-7c77f048a2d02e784926184a82686fa0-original.pptx&usg=AOvVaw2yQpShMcHWqkTiZGC8VuLK) regarding its details.
I have obtained the employees working on two or more projects and their respective locations:

```sql
select w."Essn", p."Plocation"
from "Works_On" w, "Project" p, "Employee" e
where p."Pnumber" = w."Pno" and w."Essn" = e."Ssn"
        and 
        w."Essn" in 
        (select w1."Essn"
        from "Works_On" w1
        group by w1."Essn"
        having count(*) >= 2
        )
```

The resulting relation looks like 
[image: this].

I need to determine those employees that work on two or more different locations. Therefore, `987987987` and `999887777` are not eligible as they are working on two different projects but at the same location. The solution I came up is to group the employees based on their `Essn` and `Plocation` attributes and determine those that are equal to one. Updated code would be:

```sql
select base."Essn", base."Plocation"
from
    (select w."Essn", p."Plocation"
    from "Works_On" w, "Project" p, "Employee" e
    where p."Pnumber" = w."Pno" and w."Essn" = e."Ssn"
        and 
        w."Essn" in 
        (select w1."Essn"
        from "Works_On" w1
        group by w1."Essn"
        having count(*) >= 2
        )
    ) as base 

group by base."Essn", base."Plocation"
having count(*) =1
```

However, this obviously is not true as it would eliminate `33344555 - Stafford`.

My question is: would it possible from the given `base` relation to determine those employees that work on more than `x` different locations?

Comment: You need to describe your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find employees that work on two different projects on two different locations you probably just need this query

```
  select w."Essn"
  from "Works_On" w
  join "Project" p on p."Pnumber" = w."Pno"
  group by w."Essn"
  having count(distinct w."Pno") > 1 and count(distinct p."Plocation") > 1
```

and having query like this should be sufficient as well

```
  select w."Essn"
  from "Works_On" w
  join "Project" p on p."Pnumber" = w."Pno"
  group by w."Essn"
  having count(distinct p."Plocation") > 1
```